# WSO2 DAS SiddhiQL: Initialize an event table and update it after

Tags: wso2, complex-event-processing, wso2-das, siddhi

I have some related questions :

1. Fisrt, I want to initialize an event table with default values and 100 rows like on this picture:

[image: How I want to initialize my event table named 'counterTable'.]

2. Second, once the initialization is done I would like to update this table. How can I execute in the same execution plan a query2 once the query1 execution is finished?
3. To finish, I have an event with 'altitude' attribute. In my execution plan, for each event, I want to increment `count1` of every row of my event table where the num column is smaller than the alitude. I tried it but that doesn't increment count of all rows.

   ```
   FROM inputStream JOIN counterTable
   SELECT count1+1 as count1, altitude as tempNum
   update counterTable on counterTable.count1 < tempNum;

   FROM inputStream JOIN counterTable
   SELECT counterTable.num as theAltitude, counterTable.count1 as countAltitude
   INSERT INTO outputStream;
   ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. If you want to initialize each time the execution plan gets deployed, you should use an in-memory event table (as shown below). Otherwise, you can simply use an [RDBMS event table](https://docs.wso2.com/display/CEP420/SiddhiQL+Guide+3.1#SiddhiQLGuide3.1-RDBMSeventtable), where it's already been initialized.
2. Queries will run in the order that they have defined, but that process will occur per each event (not as a batch, i.e if there two queries which consume from `inputStream`, when event 1 comes into `inputStream` it goes to query 1, then to query 2, and then only event 2 will get consumed..).
3. Refer to the below snippet;

   ```
   /* Define the trigger to be used with initialization */
   define trigger triggerStream at 'start';

   /* Define streams */
   define stream inputStream (altitude int);
   define stream outputStream (theAltitude long, countAltitude int);

   /* Define table */
   define table counterTable (num long, count1 int, count2 int, tempNum int);

   /* Iterate and generate 100 events */
   from triggerStream[count() < 100]
   insert into triggerStream;

   /* Using above 100 events, initialize the event table */
   from triggerStream
   select count() as num, 0 as count1, 0 as count2, 0 as tempNum
   insert into counterTable;

   /* Perform the update logic here */
   from inputStream as i join counterTable as c
       on c.count1 < i.altitude
   select c.num, (c.count1 + 1) as count1, c.count2, altitude as tempNum
   insert into updateStream;

   from updateStream
   insert overwrite counterTable
       on counterTable.num == num;

   /* Join the table and get the updated results */
   from inputStream join counterTable as c
   select c.num as theAltitude, c.count1 as countAltitude
   insert into outputStream;
   ```

Comment: I have an other issue, can I insert only the last update of counterTable (for the last event) into the outputStream because currently I have 100 rows for each events so I have a huge amount of data in my persistent data stream. Thank you in advance.

Comment: I finally fixed my issue by using 'output last X events' before 'insert into my outputStream;' in the last query.

Answer (score 0):

Table values can be initialized as follows.

```
@info(name='initialize table values')
from inputStream[count()==1]
select 1 as id, 0 as counter1, 0 as counter2, 0 as counter3
insert into counterTable;
```